# Plotting API hit count on kibana via logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk, apm

I log a message every time an API is hit, as follows:

`{"timeMillis":1685516381535,"thread":"http-nio-8460-exec-1","level":"INFO","loggerName":"com.axestrack.service.interceptor.ExecutionTimeInterceptor","message":"{\"path\":\"/user/test\",\"time\":26,\"params\":\"testParam\\u003dsomething\",\"status\":200}","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger","contextMap":{},"threadId":56,"threadPriority":5,"source":{"class":"com.axestrack.service.interceptor.ExecutionTimeInterceptor","method":"postHandle","file":"ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java","line":48},"appName":"request-tracing"}`

(I have used JSONLayout with log4j2).

This is being sent to logstash, which is then fed to elasticsearch, and is available on a Kibana dashboard.

I would like to make dashboards on Kibana, which contain the following:

1. For a given url, a time series of
   a. average response times for that URL
   b. 90/99 percentile response times
2. The top 90/99 percentile api calls in terms of response time.

I need help with the following:

1. Is this even possible on Kibana
2. How do I need to modify my logs so that elasticsearch can index better/let me plot what I described above
3. A brief description or a link on how I can plot this on Kibana.

If anyone could provide a way to explore this without logs, I'd be happy to explore that too.